# How to create a monad which allows IO but is NOT a MonadIO?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm trying to create a monad where only specific IO functions are allowed. This means that this hypothetical monad cannot be a `MonadIO` and cannot allow `liftIO` to be called.

Here's what I have till now, but I'm stuck with the `Monad` instance for `AppM`:

```
data AppM a = AppM {unwrapAppM :: ReaderT Env (LoggingT IO) a}

instance Functor AppM where
  fmap fn appm = AppM $ fmap fn (unwrapAppM appm)


instance Applicative AppM where
  pure a = AppM $ pure a
```

Comment: It has been some time since I've asked something similar, so I am not a 100% sure, but someone recommend looking at [the prompt-monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadPrompt-1.0.0.5/docs/Control-Monad-Prompt.html).You can define your IO actions as gadts and execute them much like an interpreter, thus limiting io to only what you want

Comment: You could do this with `Free`. Another alternative would be to use `mtl`-style APIs. Which specific functions do you have in mind?

Comment: The larger idea is at https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/6p0rex/restricting_io_by_io_typekindcapability/ - - using typeclass constraints to allow only specific IO capabilities, such that a function's signature immediately tells the reader what type of IO it is doing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just want to hide the `MonadIO`-ness of your `AppM`

I would go on and put in a

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
```

and change the `data` declaration to

```
newtype App a = App {runApp :: ReaderT Env (LoggingT IO) a}
              deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader Env,
                       , MonadLoggerIO }
```

Thus your `App` is no `MonadIO` if you need to `liftIO` like actions you can provide those inside of your library like

```
putStrLn :: String -> App ()
putStrLn = fmap App . liftIO Prelude.putStrLn
```

Note: the `liftIO` is for `ReaderT Env (LoggingT IO) ()` which then is wrapped into `App`, and you do not expose full IO capabilities.

### Update

Regarding the question how to implement `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad` it is just the mere task of wrapping/unwrapping:

```
instance Functor App where
   fmap f = App . fmap f . runApp

instance Applicative App where
  pure = App . pure
  mf <*> mx = App (runApp mf <*> runApp mx)

instance Monad App where
  mx >>= f = App $ (runApp mx) >>= (runApp . f)
```

the last line is the only tricky one - as

```
>>= :: ReaderT Env (LoggingT IO) a -> (a -> ReaderT Env (LoggingT IO) b) -> ReaderT Env (LoggingT IO) b
```

but `mx :: App a` and `f :: a -> App b` so we need

```
runApp :: App a -> ReaderT Env (LoggingT IO) a
```

to unwrap the result type of `f` to work in the unwrapped setting - which seems really obvious when written down, but can cause some headache, before that.

### Update2

I found that paper someone linked me a long long time a go (but in the same galaxy) from the monad reader [Ed Z. Yang -
 Three Monads (Logic, Prompt, Failure)](http://web.mit.edu/~ezyang/Public/threemonads.pdf)

Comment: Brilliant. But just for my understating, what would the code for Monad instance look like in this case?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda - updated - is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yep. Seems like what I need. Let me try it once I'm on my laptop and come back to you.

Comment: Perhaps this is very obvious (but for the benefit of future readers who may not know it) - in order to hide the `IO`-ness of `App` in this way, the `App` constructor must not be exported (i.e. `App` must be an abstract type); and you must (on recent version of GHC) add a role annotation to `App`, or `Data.Coerce.coerce` allows one to extract the internal representation even when the constructor isn't exported.